# How to efficiently sample hive table and run a query?

Tags: hive

I want to sample 100 rows from a `big_big_table` (millions and millions of rows), and run some query on these 100 rows. Mainly for testing purposes.

The way I wrote this runs for really long time, as if it reads the whole `big_big_table`, and only then take the `LIMIT 100`:

```
WITH sample_table AS (
SELECT * 
FROM big_big_table
LIMIT 100
)

SELECT name
FROM sample_table
ORDER BY name
;
```

**Question**: What's the correct/fast way of doing this?

Comment: Is table partitioned /bucketed?

Comment: @leftjoin partitioned yes, bucketed no

Answer (score 0):

Check `hive.fetch.task.*` [configuration properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/configuration+properties)

```
set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more;
set hive.fetch.task.aggr=true;
set hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold=1073741824; --1Gbyte
```

Set these properties before your query and if you are lucky, it will work without map-reduce. Also consider limiting to single partition.
It may not work depending on the storage type/serde and files size. If files are of small size/splittable and table is native, it may work fast without Map-Reduce started.

Comment: Didn't help. I switched from tez to `SET hive.execution.engine=mr;` and added `where` to select only one partition. Still large number of mappers spawned.

Comment: @SidaZhou If it works, it works for Tez also. Probably files are big. You can try virtual column to limit file name: `WHERE INPUT__FILE__NAME ='blabla_filename'`. Select it first to see which are filenames does it return(path is also included). But it maybe not good solution because you do not know filenames in advance